# Android layout_width="match_parent" in generated constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

When I create a new Android app project with Android Studio, the file `activity_main.xml` contains the following. **Why does the `TextView` have `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes with values `wrap_content`?** I thought that if the view is being laid out with constraints, the `layout_width` and `layout_height` are supposed to have values `0dp`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if you have constraints attached with your view then 0dp means 2 things. Either it's match_constraint which is equal to match_parent or it's really 0 dp. In either case you don't need 0dp for a textview do you ?

Comment: Because you can set it? ideally you'd just do match constraints on the view in the layout and set constraint margin from the edge of the parent

Answer (score 1):

Values of the attributes layout_width and layout_height totally depends on your requirement
For more information check this link:-

For more information:-
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

Comment: But if `android:layout_width="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"` are all set, isn't it over constrained? Not all three will be true when the text is laid out for display.

Comment: the height and width will be wrap_content, but by using these constraints that view will be centralised horizontally

Comment: Ahh! The constraints don't actually pull the edge of the text view to the edge of the constraint layout. The constraints happen "outside" the text view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not true, depending on you situation you could use either `wrap_content` or `0dp`

> The dimension of the widgets can be specified by setting the android:layout_width and android:layout_height attributes in 3 different ways:
>
> - Using a specific dimension (either a literal value such as 123dp or a Dimension reference)
> - Using WRAP_CONTENT, which will ask the widget to compute its own size
> - Using 0dp, which is the equivalent of "MATCH_CONSTRAINT"

And also

> When a dimension is set to MATCH_CONSTRAINT, the default behavior is to have the resulting size take all the available space.

More details here [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)